How to test java 23 preview-features
I want to test JEP 468 (Derived Record Creation) but I'm unable to compile it.
In the JEP there is a paragraph:

This is a preview language feature, disabled by default
To try the examples in JDK 23 you must enable preview features:

Compile the program with javac --release 23 --enable-preview Main.java and run it with java --enable-preview Main; or,

When using the source code launcher, run the program with java --enable-preview Main.java; or,

When using jshell, start it with jshell --enable-preview.





So I installed jdk 23 (for windows > sha256: b18897bec6b1c6e0f639d95757eb0e3b0ec3d69720f6e4631874f2f9408075c5),

changed my PATH accordingly,

executed javac --version, which returned "javac 23"

wrote the following class using the derived record creation:


public class Main {

    record Point(int x, int y) {
        public Point {
            System.out.println("Point created at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var oldLoc = new Point(1, 2);
        Point nextLoc = oldLoc with {
            x = 0;
        };
        System.out.println("New point: " + nextLoc);
    }
}


executed the command javac --release 23 --enable-preview .\src\Main.java
and got the following compiler error:

.\src\Main.java:14: Fehler: ';' erwartet
        Point nextLoc = oldLoc with {
                              ^
.\src\Main.java:14: Fehler: Keine Anweisung
        Point nextLoc = oldLoc with {
                               ^
.\src\Main.java:14: Fehler: ';' erwartet
        Point nextLoc = oldLoc with {
                                   ^
3 Fehler


How can I get this to compile (and eventually run)?

That JEP is still in Candidate status which means it hasn't been accepted yet - the JDK Features list doesn't mention it.

If this JEP was to be included in Java 23, it would have "Status Targeted" and "Release 23" in its header instead of "Status Candidate". I guess either someone was optimistic about its inclusion in Java 23, or it was initially targeted for Java 23, but retracted/reverted to candidate status before Java 23 was finalized.

As noted in the Comments above, the feature JEP 468: Derived Record Creation (Preview) is not included in Java 23.

The JEP’s status is candidate rather than Closed / Delivered.
The JEP is not listed as a feature on the Java 23 project page.

So, keep an eye on Java 24.
